# Creating a time handling function (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a few cells that schedule a list of employees depending on a start time. (In this case, the start time is indicated by the cell named 'Time'.)

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(Time,"h:mm AM/PM")&" - "&TEXT(Time+TIME(10,30,0),"h:mm AM/PM"))
```

It works fine but now I want to implement a feature that will allow the user to specify how long the shift could be by entering the amount of hours into a cell. (In my worksheet I used a cell named DayShift)

What would I do to my Function in order to allow the addition of how long the shift is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(Time,"h:mm AM/PM")&" - "&TEXT(Time+TIME(0,Hours*60,0),"h:mm AM/PM"))
```

Where `Hours` is the cell with the number of hours (ie, 10.5 for your current example).